# Sails.js/Waterline cascading delete for a many-to-many association

Tags: sails.js, waterline, cascading-deletes

As shown in that [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23486612/3266689), having no support for cascading (cascading deletes in particular) in Waterline there is a workaround for *one-to-many* associations by using the `afterDestroy` (or `afterUpdate` for soft-delete) lifecycle callback and deleting the associated records with a second query. This is possible via `ManyModel.destroy({ oneModel: _.pluck(destroyedOneModels, "id") })` from within `afterDestroy`.

How do we do that for a *many-to-many* relationship (having in mind that a junction table is used internally and we have to delete records from it)?

Answer (score 10):

I did some tests using the [`Pet` / `User` example from the documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/many-to-many) with sails 0.11.

Writting this lifecycle callback in the `Pet` model deletes all the `users` associated to a `pet` *before* deleting it.

```js
// models/Pet.js
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name:'string',
    color:'string',
    owners: {
        collection: 'user',
        via: 'pets'
    }
  },

  beforeDestroy: function(criteria, cb) {
    // Destroy any user associated to a deleted pet
    Pet.find(criteria).populate('owners').exec(function (err, pets){
      if (err) return cb(err);
      pets.forEach(function(recordToDestroy) {
        User.destroy({id: _.pluck(recordToDestroy.owners, 'id')}).exec(function(err) {
          console.log('The users associated to the pet ' + recordToDestroy.name + ' have been deleted');
        });
      });
      cb();
    })
  }

};
```

I couldn't do it in the `afterDestroy` lifecycle callback because the many-to-many properties of the deleted records are missing there.

Waterline is deleting the records of the junction table automatically.

The problem with this feature is that it probably would delete too much things if some pets share some owners. Following the example of the documentation, if you delete the pet *Rainbow Dash*, you will delete the users *Mike*, *Cody* and *Gabe*, and the pets *Pinkie Pie* and *Applejack* would be orphans.

If you define a many-to-many relation like this one but you know that the pets cannot have any owner in common, then it works fine. Otherwise, you should add a test to check that you will not make another pet an orphan.